# Separate Woocommerce Registration Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know this question has been asked already, but the answer wasn't very clear.

I'm looking for a way to put the woocommerce registration form onto a separate Wordpress page called 'Register'

Comment: So you need to make that one yourself via pure PHP

Answer (score 1):

Create a page in wordpress and add

```
[woocommerce_my_account][/woocommerce_my_account]
```

on it. That should do it.